# Using Interop with C#, Excel Save changing original. How to negate this?

Tags: c#, excel

The problem: Loading an excel spreadsheet template.  Using the Save command with a different filename and then quitting the interop object.  This ends up saving the original template file. Not the result that is liked.

```
public void saveAndExit(string filename)
{        
    excelApplication.Save(filename);
    excelApplication.Quit();
}
```

Original file opened is c:\testing\template.xls
The file name that is passed in is c:\testing\7777 (date).xls

Does anyone have an answer?

(The answer I chose was the most correct and thorough though the wbk.Close() requires parameters passed to it.  Thanks.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excel interop is pretty painful.  I dug up an old project I had, did a little fiddling, and I think this is what you're looking for.  The other commenters are right, but, at least in my experience, there's a lot more to calling SaveAs() than you'd expect if you've used the same objects (without the interop wrapper) in VBA.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wbk = excelApplication.Workbooks[0];  //or some other way of obtaining this workbook reference, as Jason Z mentioned
wbk.SaveAs(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing);
wbk.Close();
excelApplication.Quit();
```

Gotta love all those Type.Missings.  But I think they're necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an ExcelApplication, you can use the Workbook object and call the SaveAs() method.  You can pass the updated file name in there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the SaveAs from the Worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ditto on the SaveAs
2. Whenever I have to do Interop I create a separate VB.NET class library and write the logic in VB. It is just not worth the hassle doing it in C#